# How to edit default marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Kindly check this map view: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/map_language/map_lang.html

If you click on A or B, it will show location name in default marker. I wish to show some custom texts here. How can I do that?
My JavaScript code for this is:

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var oldDirections = [];
var currentDirections = null;


//getting latitude and longitude from address
var latitude;
var longitude;



var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address = "Downtown Berkeley";
geocoder.geocode( { "address": address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
  {
      // do something with the geocoded result
      //
      latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
      longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng()
      alert(latitude )
  }
});

//map initialize    

function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 13,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.879,151.235),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

//adding marker 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    (
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longitude),
            map: map,
            title: "Click me"
        }
    );
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Location info:<br/>Country Name:<br/>LatLng:"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        // Calling the open method of the infoWindow 
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });


directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    "map": map,
    "preserveViewport": true,
    "draggable": true

});
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));

google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, "directions_changed",
  function() {
    if (currentDirections) {
      oldDirections.push(currentDirections);

    }
    currentDirections = directionsDisplay.getDirections();

  });



calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
var start = "El Cerrito del Norte";
var end = "Downtown Berkeley";
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a business/"default" location marker and infoWindow to Google Maps (v3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454782/how-to-add-a-business-default-location-marker-and-infowindow-to-google-maps-v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set that content in the createInfoWindow() method.