# How to activate this context window in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Started to work with Google Maps JavaScript API v3, but in all my maps this info window is missing. Researching "Infowindow" just offers information about tag windows that open if you click on the map badge I can set.

Anybody knows how to activate this "context window" which is activated in the Google Maps iframe example? See the picture below…

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a business/"default" location marker and infoWindow to Google Maps (v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454782/how-to-add-a-business-default-location-marker-and-infowindow-to-google-maps-v)

Answer (score -1):

The Answer to your questions is NO, there is no way to activate a context window in the API other than the info windows.

May I suggest to use a `div` element and with simple CSS you can position your div in front of your map or anywhere you want, and with the Google Maps API you fill this div with any info you want.

I did not find any info about that context window in the docs neither, but inspecting Google Maps I see that all of that is pure HTML.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I don't understand what am I hardcoding in this context?